# Customize Windows 10 Recovery Environment menu items visibility/order

Tags: windows, windows-10, recovery

My goal is to customize the Windows Recovery Environment user interface so that some recovery options are not visible, and other ones are visible at first level of the navigation.

Example, to reach the "System Image Recovery" procedure you have to navigate this way:

1. Click "Troubleshoot"
2. Click "Advanced Options"
3. Click "System Image Recovery"

I would like to have the "System Image Recovery" button right at the top-level screen.
Also, other buttons like "System Restore" shall not be visible.

I readed [the docs from MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/customize-windows-re) but I don't see any tutorial on how to do that. Is it actually possible?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible, but keep in mind that if one were to boot from any windows 10 install medium, they would get the default recovery environment, not your customized one. If you use it to hide things to protect your system, then it is a lost cause. Also keep in mind that any feature update will likely reset the recovery back to its default.

Comment: Thanks , I'm aware of your hints but it is not a problem since I'm customizing the deployment of a "closed system", not general use.